# How can I get two divs next to each other with display:flex on the first div?

Tags: html, css

**How can I get the two divs next to eachother ?**

```css
.web-info-header-left{
  width:20px;
  height:50px;
  padding: 2px 15px;
  float:left;
  background: #1798e5;
  display:flex;
  align-items: center;
  color:white;
}
.web-info{
  display: inline-block;
  background:#1799e3;
  width:100%;
  padding: 5px 5px;
  color:white;
}
.container{
  max-width:750px;
  margin-left:auto;
  margin-right:auto;
}
```

```html
  <div class="container">
    <div class="web-info-header-left">
      <i class="material-icons">&#xE031;</i>
    </div>
  <div class="web-info">
    Click here to read about the changes that came in the new design update.
  </div>
</div>
<style>
```

**Codepen Link :** https://codepen.io/audn/pen/BZEMxd

Comment: What is problem here ?

Comment: How can I get the two divs next to eachother? @RïshïKêshKümar

Answer (score 1):

Always simplify, simplify and then simplify a bit more. For flexbox layouts you need to start thinking in rows and columns:

- Is my container a **row of columns** or a **column of rows**?
- Are the child elements **row of columns** or a **column of rows** or just simple flexed container?

These two questions alone will make your **flexible** life already a lot easier.

Have a look at my commented code in which I moved shared code to one rule block and simplified your code a lot.

Ask for more info if so required.

```css
/* parent/child shared rules */
.container, .web-info-header-left, .web-info {
    display: flex;  /* make them all flexible containers, default "row nowrap" */

    /* center content */
    justify-content: center; /* horizontal */
    align-items    : center; /* vertical   */

    background:#1799e3; color:white;
}

/* PARENT ROW */
.container { /* a row of two columns */
    max-width: 750px; /* maximum container width */
    margin: 0 auto;   /* center horizontally in parent */
}

/* CHILD COLUMNS */
/* align-self = auto, which makes children stretch to given space */
.web-info-header-left { /* column 1: fixed width/height */
    width : 50px; /* a nice little square */
    height: 50px;
}
.web-info { /* column 2: flexible width/height */
    flex: 1; /* fill remaining parent space (flex-grow, default "0") */
}

/* DEBUG */
*   { outline: 1px dashed } /* show element outlines for debug, remove when done */
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="web-info-header-left" ><i class="material-icons">&#xE031;</i></div>
    <div class="web-info">Click here to read about the changes that came in the new design update.</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should have use `Display: flex` on Container and `Flex` property in child `div`.

> WITH FLEX

```css
.web-info-header-left {
  padding: 10px;
  flex: 1;
  /* CHANGE AS PER YOU REQUIRED */
  background: #1798e5;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
}

.web-info {
  display: inline-block;
  background: #1799e3;
  flex: 9;
  /* CHANGE AS PER YOU REQUIRED */
  padding: 5px 5px;
  color: white;
}

.flex-class {
  display: flex;
  /* CORRECT PLACE FOR FLEX */
}

.container {
  max-width: 750px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="container flex-class">
  <div class="web-info-header-left">
    <i class="material-icons">&#xE031;</i>
  </div>
  <div class="web-info">
    Click here to read about the changes that came in the new design update.
  </div>
</div>
<style>
```

> WITHOUT FLEX

```
.web-info-header-left {
  padding: 10px;
  width: 10%;
  background: #1798e5;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  line-height: 2;
}

.web-info {
  width: 90%;
  background: #1799e3;
  padding: 5px 5px;
  color: white;
}

.flex-class {
    display: inline-flex;
}

.container {
  max-width: 750px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
```

Comment: That will make the image in the first div to not become centered horizont.

Comment: display:flexs ruins the header, any way without adding flex to containert?

Comment: for header container issue, you can add `display: flex` to new class so it will be applied to only that div.
without flex you have to use `inline` or `inline-block`.

I will make without flex example.

Answer (score 0):

Try following code, u need to give **display:flex;** to **.container**.

```css
.container{
  max-width:750px;
  margin-left:auto;
  margin-right:auto;
  display:flex;
}

.web-info-header-left{
  width:20px;
  height:50px;
  padding: 2px 15px;
  float:left;
  background: #1798e5;
  display:flex;
  align-items: center;
  color:white;
}
.web-info{
  display: inline-block;
  background:#1799e3;
  width:100%;
  padding: 5px 5px;
  color:white;
  display:flex;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="web-info-header-left">
      <i class="material-icons">&#xE031;</i>
    </div>
  <div class="web-info">
    Click here to read about the changes that came in the new design update.
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.container{
  
  display:inline;
  float:left;
  background:#1799e3;
  width:100%;
  padding: 5px 5px;
  color:white;
}

.web-info{
margin-left:75px;
display:inline;
position: inherit;
text-align: center;


}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="web-info-header-left">
      <i class="material-icons">&#xE031;</i>
      
<div class="web-info">
    Click here to read about the changes that came in the new design update.
</div>


</div>
  
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use **display:block** style instead of **display:inline-block** in .web-info class

Answer (score 0):

Since you use fixed width settings everywhere else, just change the `width` of `.web-info` to 690px:

(The 750 of the container minus 2 x 5 px for `.web-info`s padding minus 2 x 15 px for `.web-info-header-left`s padding minus 20px `.web-info-header-left`s width: results in 690px)

VIEW IN FULL PAGE MODE - the snippet is less than 750px wide and will truncate the container....

Or look at the codepen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/dRLLdQ

```css
.web-info-header-left{
  width:20px;
  height:50px;
  padding: 2px 15px;
  float:left;
  background: #1798e5;
  display:flex;
  align-items: center;
  color:white;
}
.web-info{
  display: inline-block;
  background:#1799e3;
  width:690px;
  padding: 5px 5px;
  color:white;
}
.container{
  max-width:750px;
  margin-left:auto;
  margin-right:auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="web-info-header-left">
      <i class="material-icons">&#xE031;</i>
    </div>
  <div class="web-info">
    Click here to read about the changes that came in the new design update.
  </div>
</div>
<style>
```